# Shooting method - the direction of divergence changes sign when crossing eigenenergy (proof?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I was solving the Schrödinger equation with $V(r)=-\frac{a}{r}+br$, which, reduced to the non-dimensional form only for the radial part reads
$$\left(-\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d} z^2}+\frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{z^2}-\frac{2}{z}+\lambda z\right)u(z)=\varepsilon u (z)$$

Here, $\lambda$ is parameter (basically tweaking the strength of the conical part of the potential) and $\varepsilon$ is the energy and $u(z)$ is a function s.t. $u (0) = 0$ and $u (z) \sim z^{l+1}$ when $z$ is small. Ideally, if $\varepsilon$ is an eigenvalue, then the solution also satisfies $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to\infty}u(z)=0$.

In practice, if you implement a stepping scheme from $z=0$ to larger values of $z$, the solution will eventually diverge (or oscillate like crazy if $\varepsilon$ is far away from any eigenvalue). I noticed, that numerically, whenever I just cross the "correct" eigenvalue $\varepsilon$, the direction of divergence changes sign. For example, if $\lambda = 0$ (hydrogen atom), the first eigenvalue is $\varepsilon=-1$. If $\varepsilon$ is set to $-1.001$ and the solution $u (z)\to -\infty$ for large $z$, then for $\varepsilon = -0.999$ the solution $u(z)\to+ \infty$ instead. Same is true near every higher energy and for $\lambda\ne 0$.

I naturally expect the solution to diverge if $\varepsilon$ does not match eigenvalues, but I find it interesting that the sign of this divergence always changes when $\varepsilon$ crosses over an eigenvalue.

**My question:**

---

Can I gain some insight into this sign changing from the differential equation?

Is this true for a wide variety of potentials when solving for bound states by the shooting method, or is there something special about this class of potentials I chose?

What exactly is the main reason for this sign flipping?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @LutzLehmann Plug in the ansatz $u (z) = z^\alpha$ and assume $z$ is small. Nevertheless, if chosen starting values $u (0) = 0$ and $u (h) = h^{\ell + 1}$ it works (numerically, if the initial step is of size $h$), it gives correct levels at least for the H atom.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I somehow added a $\frac{d}{dz}$ to the fraction $\frac2z$ while reading it. The characteristic polynomial is then $0=-m(m-1)+l(l+1)$ which has solutions $m=l+1$ and $m=-l$.

Comment: Yes, exactly, and I threw the solution $m = - \ell$ away for obvious reasons...thus $z^{\ell+1}$ is how it's supposed to start around zero.

Answer (score 0):

If you trace the function $ε\mapsto u_ε(T)$ for some large value of $T$, then the graph will be continuous and its roots simple (if the eigenvalues are simple, which they usually are). The roots are close to the eigenvalues, and the values close-by change sign at the root. The larger $T$, the steeper the slope, so that without any renormalization it might look like a jump from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ or the other way around.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly what these roots are...just to clarify, we fix $z = T$ for some large $T$ and look at the value $u (T)$ as a function of $\varepsilon$? Then I understand that the roots happen approximately at eigenvalues (approximately if $T$ is finite), but how do we know that the eigenvalues are simple? I think you're on the right track, if we can show this, then the sign flipping follows intuitively.

Comment: There you would have to look into Sturm-Liouville theory, I vaguely remember that it has to do with the root structure of the eigenfunctions. But in parametrized problems it probably can happen that eigenvalues cross, my suspicion would be for the lowest two.

Comment: In this problem, the eigenvalues do cross (if by that you mean that by varying $\lambda$ sometimes two smoothly extruded levels from lower $\lambda$ to higher $\lambda$ cross, i.e. at some point they have the same value), but not for the same value of $\ell$ (e.g. $n \ell = 43$ crosses with $30$ where $n$ is the same as for H atom, but never for the same value of $\ell$), so it wasn't really a problem, because the crossing happens for different $\ell$, thus when looking for the energy eigenvalue, it's a different equation really...